# How to wait and display progress information while waiting for an API to return a value

Tags: python

I have the below code where I am waiting for a method call to return a response. This response may take more than 10 to 15 seconds.

I need to display a progress message while user wait for the method to return the response.
My while condition doesn't seems to display the progress bar though.

```
response = my_api.execute("get some data")
# There is a 10-15 minute delay here...
i = 0
while response is None:
  sys.stdout.write('\r')
  sys.stdout.write("Fetching MO attribute [%-20s] %d%%" % ('=' * i, 5 * i))
  sys.stdout.flush()
  sleep(0.25)
  i += 1

if response.get_output() != "1 instance(s)":
        raise MyError('Could not fetch data. )

for line in response.get_output():
        # Do the actual processing
```

Comment: Your while loop is only executed after `my_api.execute()` has returned, and obviously at this point `response` is not `None` so the while loop body is never entered.

Answer (score 0):

You need threads, one for the main background process, and one for the display process:

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import itertools


done = False
response = None

def animate():        
    i = 0
    while response is None:
      sys.stdout.write('\r')
      sys.stdout.write("Fetching MO attribute [%-20s] %d%%" % ('=' * i, 5 * i))
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(0.25)
      i += 1

t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
t.start()

# background process
response = my_api.execute("get some data")
done = True
```

Comment: What is the number 500000 in range here? This makes my code wait for too long and it even go beyond 100% as 180%...230% etc

Comment: replaced with while loop. what youll need to do is decide on the progress bar itself, on checkpoints that drive the bar so that it stays within the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

There's an integrated library in python that does this.

Look into tqdm [demo](https://notebooks.rmotr.com/hans-meucci/tqdm-6e80c6fb/lab).

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

It's extremely useful and doesn't require you to build one from scratch.

If you do want to build something from scratch I believe you'll need to use threading, as the previous answer states.